# Titanium, gridlayout

Tags: xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

How can one go about making a grid layout in XML. for example say i wanted a 4x4 board. would i have to just make 16 buttons and format them useing jss? for example this is what i have, but is not in a board format yet.

```
<Alloy>
    <Window layout="relative" backgroundColor="white">

        <Button class="button left-buttons">square</Button>
        <Button class="button left-buttons" top="40">square</Button>
        <Button class="button left-buttons" top="80">square</Button>

        <Label id="User" left="100" top="120" text=">(NULL)<"></Label>

        <Button class="button right-buttons"  >square</Button>
        <Button class="button right-buttons" top="40">square/square</Button>
        <Button class="button right-buttons" top="80">square</Button>

        <Button class="Games" top="200">square</Button>
        <Button class="Games" top="280">square</Button>
        <Button top="360">square</Button>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: also i can not find any documentation on XML formats for titanium, if you happen to know a link to one could you point me in the right direction, please and thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by XML formats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a horizontal layout, and set your container view to the size of the screen. The horizontal layout will layout the children views in rows. You may have to do a little math to get it right, or just use percentage widths.

Here is a simple example of an unstyled 2x2 board to get you started:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window layout="horizontal" horizontalWrap="true" backgroundColor="white">
        <Button width="50%" height="50%" title="TopLeft"/>
        <Button width="50%" height="50%" title="TopRight"/>
        <Button width="50%" height="50%" title="BottomLeft"/>
        <Button width="50%" height="50%" title="BottomRight"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

As for"XML Formats" do you mean [this guide on Alloy's XML Markup?](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup)

Comment: As to the documentation yes but is there a more indepth documentation. also is it better to do the whole layout of a window in XML and use JS just for the functionality of the window, because this is how i am currently approaching this project? and thank you for your help :-)

Comment: That documentation is about as in depth as I have found, don't be afraid to experiment! I usually leave the view layout to the .xml, the styling to the .tss files, and everything else goes in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of widgets you could use.

**[gridWidget](https://github.com/albinotonnina/it.numidia.gridWidget)**
A titanium alloy widget for grids, using a tableview.

**[buttonGrid](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/widgets/com.appcelerator.buttongrid)**
 
Appcelerators own titanium alloy widget that creates a grid of buttons with some animation effects.
Reasonably customisable. The Titanium APIv3 docs include usage and tutorial.